# Get all users for a certain claim?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

For ASP.NET Identity 2.0:

Does anybody know how to get "all users that have a given claim assigned"?

Let's say I have a claim with type="ArticleId" and value="1".

How can I get all users that have this claim? I really couldn't figure it out .. so, thanks for any help!!

Comment: in **ASP.NET Core** there is a specific method for this purpose: [UserManager<TUser>.GetUsersForClaimAsync(Claim) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getusersforclaimasync?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this one.

```
var userContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

var users = userContext.Users.ToList(); Or 

var users = UserManager.Users.ToList();

var userfilter = users.Where(u => u.Claims.Any(t => t.ClaimType == "ArticleId" && t.ClaimValue == "1"));
```

Comment: DSR again. You really seem to be an expert for ASP.NET Identity. Thanks again for your help!! It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use the method `UserManager<TUser>.GetUsersForClaimAsync(Claim)` as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.getusersforclaimasync?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Using a separate context to manipulate users, roles and claims is bad practice as it might mess up with the EF tracking.