# Get all users with a given claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm working on an aspnet core 1.0 project, I've recently understood what claims are and how to use them to achieve policy based authorization.

### What I'm trying to acheive:

I want to get all users that are authorized with a given policy (i.e. users that have a given claim, let's say `Claim {Type = "CanReceiveXReport", Value = True}`)

The code I'd expect to do this is something like:

```
public static IQueryable<User> WithClaim(this IQueryable<User> users, string claimName) =>
    users
        .Include(u=> u.Claims)
        .Where(u=> u.Claims.Any(c=> c.ClaimType == claimName));
```

### The problem:

When I run the above code, for all users, `user.Claims` is always empty. I've also tried to materialize the query by adding a `ToList()` after the `Include()` with no success.

---

When I realized this wasn't working I expected there to be a `ClaimsManager<T>` of some sort to do this kind of operations.

All the apis and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40491035/2226079) I've found are focused on getting claims for a single user.

I know I could do something like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26389535/2226079) but I rather not do that, I want that query to be run in the database.

I imagine it's possible to create a stored procedure, but I'd rather mantain my domain logic in my app.

### Versions:

(That I think are relevant)

```
{
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserManager.cs#L1940) method in UserManager:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of users from the user store who have the specified <paramref name="claim"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="claim">The claim to look for.</param>
/// <returns>
/// A <see cref="Task{TResult}"/> that represents the result of the asynchronous query, a list of <typeparamref name="TUser"/>s who
/// have the specified claim.
/// </returns>
public virtual Task<IList<TUser>> GetUsersForClaimAsync(Claim claim)
{
    ThrowIfDisposed();
    var store = GetClaimStore();
    if (claim == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(claim));
    }
    return store.GetUsersForClaimAsync(claim, CancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I also found this method, but the I would need to restrict my search with a claim Value, which doesn't work for my particular case. I looked through that method's implementation and I'm writing my own version that ignore claim value.

Answer (score 0):

I use a custom query to pull Users with a particular claim type for Roles.  I have the claim type hard-coded here but this probably would work for your case if you pass in a variable.

```
var usersWithRoles = from u in _context.Users
                     join r in _context.UserClaims.Where(x => x.ClaimType == "RoleId") on u.Id equals r.UserId into ur
                     from defaultRole in ur.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new UserBaseModel() { 
                          Id = u.Id,
                          FirstName = u.FirstName,
                          LastName = u.LastName, 
                          Email = u.Email,
                          RoleId = defaultRole.ClaimValue == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(defaultRole.ClaimValue)
                     };
```